# Insert a column value to database using session

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqlcommand

I want to insert a value into a table which comes from a session variable.The code that i have written is:

```
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double balance;
    double reward;
    if((double.TryParse(lblBalance.Text, out balance) && (double.TryParse(lblReward.Text, out reward))))
    {
    Session["FinalBalance"] = balance + reward;
    }
    else
    {
// some kind of error handling
    }
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblRegister('Balance') values('@FinalBalance')", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalBalance", Session["FinalBalance"].ToString());
    }
}
```

But when i click the submit button,the code doesnt throw any exception and doesnt insert the needful.What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the command object but not executing the query. You have to call [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on Command object to insert record.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblRegister(Balance) values(@FinalBalance)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinalBalance", Session["FinalBalance"].ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
}
```

Comment: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You have to call ExecuteNonQuery, make sure you have correct spelling, check this link about the ExecuteNonQuery, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It says Invalid column 'Balance'.But i have a column with that name.

Comment: Remove the quotes from the column names Balance and also parameter @FinalBalance from the query

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I see that i cannot use 'Insert' to add a value which is already there in the table.For that i have to use 'Update'.So i can use the same query by just replacing insert with update?

Comment: The syntax of query will change like,  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblRegister SET Balance = @FinalBalance", con);

Comment: Thanks.I used a stored procedure using the same query above.